# Redirect Search API view result (Leaflet map) to display in a pane

Tags: 7, views, search, panels

The particular Search function starts as Full Panel Page in a style to a Google Maps Location Search page; Search Input (Block) to the top left overlaid on a current Leaflet map based on the logged-in users Postcode. (It is overlaid with CSS using z-Index).

I'm confused over what is required to make the required Search Result Data View (Leaflet map) show in the same Panel Pane Window.

The user can after the above viewpoint window, again Search via the Search Block with the following next results this time to display in the same Panels Page or a Variant (As it will show the Views Context Pane) again full page Leaflet display with the said results and again with the Search Input Block again the the top left. (I'm not bothered if is the same window or a second Variant)

For example, an initial Panel Page is named: <dealers/local/mapping> which is a a two pane layout (left/Right). The Search input block is to the left whilst the initial map is to the right (set at 12 columns).
The additional search results (as a View (Indexed) would show again in the right Column Pane as a 12-column full page display. So the path would result asL <dealers/local/mapping/search-api-results/cheshire*> *cheshire being the locality the user entered to search for and displays the relevant mapping which I can add Facets/Proximity etc to it.

Currently, the search results only show the Results Page View by itself and not in any panel pane, which I require.

For hours (and I'm mean over some 8 hours over 2 days!) I have tried to get my head around what needs to be 'plugged in to what' to get the second stage Search API results to display in a second Panel Page so I can also include Search API Facets.

I've looked for hints, tips across Stack and Drupal.Stack, old 'tutorials' online (harking back to 2010!) and simply cannot find any hint, tip, or workout.
Somebody please help!

Comment: I appear to have the </search-page-name-api/!keywords> disabled and whilst using a View previously to show the results, it wasn't going to this 'in-code' panel page or any custom future variants. I'll have a play around and see how far I can get. I presume that given the multiple Search API pages one can have, they have to return to this System Panel and be matched to any Variants you may need, in my case, I need 4-5 Search API result returns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I appeared not to have the used the </search-page-name-api/!keywords> 'enabled' into my Panel Pages relevant to the custom API Search Page I had made and at first I was trying to build via a standard Panel Page.
You have to use the </search-page-name-api/!keywords> which works by first creating a custom Search API page (for example, trade-shops-page-api, if based ona Search DB/Index called similar) then, after which that named api-page will appear in the Pane Page lists as a new page </search-page-name-api/!keywords> albeit not enabled. Once enabled, you can work around that pages' Variants to create what you need and in order to my question, the Search API results will appear after you have done some Views Pane etc. In my case, I was able to do the Search API Results on the Pages Right Column Pane and 3-Facets in the Left Pane, with a 'floating' Search Input Box which sat 'Absolute' top left of the map. A certain amount of CSS work also was needed.